# Heroku deployment for React app getting a 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, graphql

I've made a react project that uses nodejs, graphql, apollo, express, and mongo DB.
I'm struggling to get it deployed through Heroku.

first, when I deployed it, it failed and said I needed to add a build pack. I've gone through and gotten an idea of what buildpacks are. However, I'm more vague on if I need multiple buildpacks for my application. So I've added both a nodejs buildpack and a create-react-app buildpack. This is the furthest I've reached as it deploys with a 404 error.

One thing to note is that that the nodejs buildpack requires a package.json file in the [root folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkCjw.png), though mine were both in my client and server folders. Not sure if I structured it wrong? So I went ahead and npm init in the root folder to create a package.json not knowing if that's an adequate solution.

I've checked the Heroku logs and getting a few errors it seems:

[herokulogs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWusk.png)

I've also read somewhere about maybe needing a profile? which is not something I entirely understand yet.

As you can tell, I'm new to this and still learning a lot. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction as I'd like to see this thing through. Please let me know if you'd like to have access to my codebase.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are using one heroku server for both front-end and back-end.

If so, they must be separate.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that `npm start` throws that error. How did you defined it in your package.json and can you execute it on your local machine?

Have you read the documentation for the Node.js [Buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks)?